# Why does gulp-useref does not seem to work with a comment in the replacement section?

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-useref

I am trying to build a gulp pipeline – I want to inject some CSS into my `index.html` (this works fine) and then grab all the other links from source `index.html` and replace them in the outputted version.

I noticed that the [`useref`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-useref) call is mangling the output *if* the templated section to replace includes an **HTML comment** (see example below for the line `COMMENT`). It’s easiest to demonstrate with code:

#### `index.html` (source file)

```html
<!-- build:css styles/app.css-->
<!--COMMENT-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/.tmp/styles.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

#### `gulpfile.js` task

```js
gulp.task('optimizeReplace', function () {
    var assets = $.useref.assets({ searchPath: './' });

    return gulp
        .src('./src/client/index.html')
        .pipe(assets)
        .pipe(assets.restore())
        .pipe($.useref())  //THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE; IF INJECT IS NOT RUN FIRST IT IS MANGLED
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/'));
});
```

#### Output (`index.html`)

```html
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/lib.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app.css-->" <!--COMMENT>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
```

The problem is easier to see in HTML, but the `COMMENT` HTML comment looses the end half of its tag, so everything after it thinks it is a comment.

The reason I want to put a comment inside the replacement section is that the comment is actually a [gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject) statement which injects some other references before I do the `useref`. I simplified it down to a simple HTML comment causing the problem.

This is the line that causes the problem: `.pipe($.useref())`

FYI I am following [John Papa’s course on Pluralsight](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/javascript-build-automation-gulpjs) where he uses this exact mechanism to inject some CSS and then replace them – (the `inject:css` HTML comment delimiters are mangled after a `useref`):

```html
<!-- build:css styles/app.css-->
<!-- inject:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/.tmp/styles.css">
<!-- endinject -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

How can I get the `useref()` to replace the template with the correct links *but* leave the HTML comment intact?

Thanks.

Comment: The version of `gulp-useref` is different!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is version change check documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-useref
here you have an example:

```
gulp.task('optimize', ['templateCache', 'images'], function(){

    var templateCache = config.temp + config.templateCache.files;

    return gulp
    .src(config.index)
    .pipe($.plumber())
    .pipe($.inject(gulp.src(templateCache, {read: false}, {starttag: ''})))
    .pipe($.useref({ searchPath: './' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.build));
});
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Comments are stripped out but there are exceptions. IE conditional comments are preserved so you could make a request there or write a pull request and see if it gets accepted. Here is the repo:

https://github.com/digisfera/useref

Answer (score 0):

You can try node-useref instead of gulp-useref which preserve IE Conditional Comments

```
<!-- build:js scripts/combined.js   -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/this.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/that.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Result will be

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="scripts/combined.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Or try to put your comment out of your building code like this:

```
<!--COMMENT-->
<!-- build:css styles/app.css-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/.tmp/styles.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Answer (score 0):

> The reason I want to put a comment inside the replacement section is that the comment is actually a gulp-inject statement which injects some other references before I do the use-ref.

Could you use some other tag instead of a comment to do the same job? You could, for example, use a tag with a `data-` attribute set that contains the value that you are currently storing in the comment text.